# How to backup solr sollection?

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and trying to backup a solr collection so i checked out the [official docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-backup) and when i run the command :-

```
curl "http://10.24.210.283:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=feed-test_backup&collection=my-test-collection&location=/mnt/dataApp/solr-backup"
```

I am running into this error :-

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":0},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"specified location file:///mnt/dataApp/solr-backup does not exist.",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: specified location file:///mnt/dataApp/solr-backup does not exist.\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.
CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.lambda$static$33(CollectionsHandler.java:1111)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.execute(CollectionsHandler.java:1326)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.
CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:266)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.
CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:254)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:211)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:842)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:808)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:559)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:420)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:352)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:590)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n",
    "code":500}}
```

I have checked and the file does exist in the location.

```
"msg":"specified location file:///mnt/dataApp/solr-backup does not exist.",
```

So i can use some assistance. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: If you run ls against the path - `ls -al /mnt/dataApp/solr-backup` - do the user that Solr runs under have access to the directory? (and access to the parent directories)

Comment: The directory needs to exist on the backup server and be mounted on the Solr servers.